# Fatal error running an SWT application from OpenOffice

Tags: swt, openoffice.org

I have an [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) Java addon application. I'm calling [SWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit) from an `XActionListener`. Loading of SWT is done dynamically using a special class loader. The SWT window displays well, but when I hit the close button of an SWT window I get an error. I'm attaching the error file generated by this error.

What is the meaning of this error?

**My SWT code**

```
 final Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    shell.setSize(500, 375);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");
    final Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setUrl(location);

    try {
        try {
            shell.open();
            shell.layout();
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                    display.sleep();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                shell.dispose();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        display.dispose();
    }
```

-------Error file-------

```
        A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

          EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x77779c21, pid=968, tid=2176

         JRE version: 6.0_26-b03
         Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
         Problematic frame:
         C  [ntdll.dll+0x59c21]
    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0ad67400):  VMThread [stack: 0x26160000,0x26af0000] [id=3688]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffff

Registers:
EAX=0xfffffff8, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000008, EDX=0x00000e68
ESP=0x26aeebfc, EBP=0x26aeec04, ESI=0x0acd0000, EDI=0x0f97760c
EIP=0x77779c21, EFLAGS=0x00010282

Top of Stack: (sp=0x26aeebfc)
0x26aeebfc:   26aeed10 0f9c5d1c 26aeec50 7c3420d6
0x26aeec0c:   0acd0000 00000000 00000000 0f97760c
0x26aeec1c:   0f9c5d1c 26aeed10 00000000 0f97760c
0x26aeec2c:   7c38b348 001a0018 73bb19c4 26aeec18
0x26aeec3c:   26aee808 26aeec7c 7c34240d 7c37a368
0x26aeec4c:   ffffffff 26aeec8c 7c34c0b4 00000000
0x26aeec5c:   0f97760c 00000003 26aeed10 d1eb85ce
0x26aeec6c:   61c267d4 ffffffff 26aeec5c 26aee808

Instructions: (pc=0x77779c21)
0x77779c01:   85 3e f7 02 00 53 33 db f6 46 48 01 0f 85 75 f7
0x77779c11:   02 00 8b 45 10 a8 07 0f 85 57 f7 02 00 83 c0 f8
0x77779c21:   80 78 07 05 0f 84 33 f7 02 00 f6 40 07 3f 0f 84
0x77779c31:   37 f7 02 00 3b c3 0f 84 5a f7 02 00 8a 48 07 80


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]

Stack: [0x26160000,0x26af0000],  sp=0x26aeebfc,  free space=9786k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x59c21]  RtlSizeHeap+0x35
C  0x7c3420d6  msize+0x34
C  0x7c34c0b4  _dllonexit+0x1f
C  0x0f94a1ba  JVM_FindSignal+0xce49a
C  0x0f880c8f  JVM_FindSignal+0x4f6f
C  0x0f8811be  JVM_FindSignal+0x549e
C  0x7c349565  endthreadex+0xa0
C  [kernel32.dll+0x4ed6c]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637f5]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xef
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637c8]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xc2

VM_Operation (0x00c7eb20): Exit, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x0acda800


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0adaa400 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=3524, stack(0x3dc40000,0x3e5d0000)]
  0x2e14d800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4088, stack(0x2ef20000,0x2f8b0000)]
  0x2e054c00 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3800, stack(0x38840000,0x391d0000)]
  0x2e04b800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2636, stack(0x321d0000,0x32b60000)]
  0x2e04a000 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=316, stack(0x31840000,0x321d0000)]
  0x2e009800 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1068, stack(0x30e40000,0x317d0000)]
  0x2df4f000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1792, stack(0x2e3b0000,0x2ed40000)]
  0x0acda800 JavaThread "Thread-20" [_thread_blocked, id=1636, stack(0x002f0000,0x00c80000)]
  0x0fda8800 JavaThread "Thread-16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=692, stack(0x2d490000,0x2de20000)]
  0x0adc4000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3664, stack(0x2bf90000,0x2c920000)]
  0x0adc3000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3520, stack(0x2b5a0000,0x2bf30000)]
  0x0adaa000 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1352, stack(0x2ab00000,0x2b490000)]
  0x0ada9000 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2464, stack(0x2a0e0000,0x2aa70000)]
  0x0ada6c00 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1076, stack(0x29580000,0x29f10000)]
  0x0ad9a000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4044, stack(0x28a00000,0x29390000)]
  0x0ad99400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3100, stack(0x28030000,0x289c0000)]
  0x0ad6cc00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3940, stack(0x27640000,0x27fd0000)]
  0x0ad6b800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=840, stack(0x26b00000,0x27490000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x0ad67400 VMThread [stack: 0x26160000,0x26af0000] [id=3688]

VM state:at safepoint (shutting down)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x0acd8528] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0ad67400

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 1272K [0x12120000, 0x12670000, 0x17670000)
  eden space 4416K,  23% used [0x12120000, 0x122257c8, 0x12570000)
  from space 512K,  44% used [0x12570000, 0x125a8940, 0x125f0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x125f0000, 0x125f0000, 0x12670000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 3039K [0x17670000, 0x18120000, 0x22120000)
   the space 10944K,  27% used [0x17670000, 0x17967e80, 0x17968000, 0x18120000)
 compacting perm gen  total 15616K, used 15451K [0x22120000, 0x23060000, 0x26120000)
   the space 15616K,  98% used [0x22120000, 0x23036dd0, 0x23036e00, 0x23060000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x10120000, 0x102a0000, 0x12120000)
 total_blobs=763 nmethods=584 adapters=123 free_code_cache=32023424 largest_free_block=25792

Dynamic libraries:
0x001d0000 - 0x002df000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\soffice.bin
0x77720000 - 0x7785c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x76340000 - 0x76414000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75a60000 - 0x75aaa000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x64d00000 - 0x64d34000     C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll
0x67670000 - 0x676bd000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\sal3.dll
0x6a6a0000 - 0x6a6ab000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\uwinapi.dll
0x75ee0000 - 0x75fa9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x75e90000 - 0x75ede000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x766a0000 - 0x766aa000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x76760000 - 0x767fd000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x778a0000 - 0x7794c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76130000 - 0x761d0000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x766b0000 - 0x766c9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x76080000 - 0x76121000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x74dc0000 - 0x74dc9000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x73bb0000 - 0x73c53000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCR90.dll
0x761d0000 - 0x76227000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x73b10000 - 0x73b17000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x77860000 - 0x77895000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x769a0000 - 0x769a6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x76460000 - 0x765bc000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x73b20000 - 0x73bae000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCP90.dll
0x71e50000 - 0x71e62000     C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x769b0000 - 0x775fa000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x6a640000 - 0x6a69e000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\sofficeapp.dll
0x61f00000 - 0x62017000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\comphelpMSC.dll
0x620c0000 - 0x6213b000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\cppuhelper3MSC.dll
0x6d960000 - 0x6d968000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\salhelper3MSC.dll
0x67190000 - 0x671c3000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\cppu3.dll
0x62060000 - 0x620c0000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\ucbhelper4MSC.dll
0x675d0000 - 0x675f7000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\deploymentmiscmi.dll
0x61e30000 - 0x61eff000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\libdb47.dll
0x61d90000 - 0x61e30000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\tlmi.dll
0x61c80000 - 0x61d85000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\basegfxmi.dll
0x6a630000 - 0x6a63b000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\i18nisolang1MSC.dll
0x61b70000 - 0x61c74000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\utlmi.dll
0x61aa0000 - 0x61b67000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\xcrmi.dll
0x61780000 - 0x61a95000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\sfxmi.dll
0x61700000 - 0x61776000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\fwemi.dll
0x62020000 - 0x62051000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\fwimi.dll
0x61620000 - 0x616fe000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\svlmi.dll
0x615d0000 - 0x61616000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\sotmi.dll
0x612a0000 - 0x615c9000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\svtmi.dll
0x10000000 - 0x1011f000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\icuuc44.dll
0x00e90000 - 0x01cd1000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\icudt44.dll
0x679a0000 - 0x679be000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\jvmfwk3.dll
0x00c80000 - 0x00d76000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\libxml2.dll
0x61020000 - 0x61295000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\tkmi.dll
0x60c90000 - 0x61018000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\vclmi.dll
0x67ba0000 - 0x67bab000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\i18npapermi.dll
0x67650000 - 0x67666000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\i18nutilMSC.dll
0x74250000 - 0x743e0000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_72d18a4386696c80\gdiplus.dll
0x73650000 - 0x73655000     C:\Windows\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x6e190000 - 0x6e1e1000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x76320000 - 0x7633f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll
0x75fb0000 - 0x7607c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x67170000 - 0x6718e000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\saxmi.dll
0x60a80000 - 0x60c83000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\sbmi.dll
0x76230000 - 0x762bf000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x743e0000 - 0x74420000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x75840000 - 0x7584c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x765c0000 - 0x765c5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x609f0000 - 0x60a7e000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\bootstrap.uno.dll
0x66370000 - 0x6638c000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\reg3.dll
0x67b90000 - 0x67ba0000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\store3.dll
0x67990000 - 0x6799f000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\xmlreader.dll
0x609d0000 - 0x609e3000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\msci_uno.dll
0x75860000 - 0x7586b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x60950000 - 0x609cd000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\configmgr.uno.dll
0x67a10000 - 0x67a19000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\localebe1.uno.dll
0x60930000 - 0x6094a000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\stocservices.uno.dll
0x70da0000 - 0x70e01000     C:\Windows\system32\wer.dll
0x60900000 - 0x60926000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\splmi.dll
0x607a0000 - 0x608fb000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\i18npool.uno.dll
0x078d0000 - 0x07a55000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\icuin44.dll
0x60760000 - 0x6079b000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\ucb1.dll
0x60580000 - 0x60755000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\fwkmi.dll
0x60530000 - 0x60579000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\ucpfile1.dll
0x73d40000 - 0x73d53000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x604e0000 - 0x6052f000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\package2.dll
0x603a0000 - 0x604d2000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\lngmi.dll
0x60050000 - 0x60396000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\xomi.dll
0x60030000 - 0x6004d000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\localedata_en.dll
0x5ffe0000 - 0x6002c000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\ucpchelp1.dll
0x063a0000 - 0x063cd000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\libxslt.dll
0x5ffc0000 - 0x5ffd1000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\fileacc.dll
0x5ff20000 - 0x5ffb9000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\deploymentmi.uno.dll
0x5fef0000 - 0x5ff1b000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\helplinkermi.dll
0x676f0000 - 0x676fa000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\ucpexpand1.uno.dll
0x5fe90000 - 0x5feeb000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\unoxmlmi.dll
0x5fe60000 - 0x5fe8b000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\sax.uno.dll
0x5fe30000 - 0x5fe53000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\dnd.dll
0x75340000 - 0x75356000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x750e0000 - 0x7511b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x75850000 - 0x7585e000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x5fe10000 - 0x5fe29000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\fsstorage.uno.dll
0x74730000 - 0x748ce000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
0x76800000 - 0x7699d000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75b90000 - 0x75bb7000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x75ab0000 - 0x75ac2000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x766d0000 - 0x76753000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x744d0000 - 0x745c5000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x74c80000 - 0x74ca1000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x76650000 - 0x76695000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x5fdc0000 - 0x5fe10000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\oleautobridge.uno.dll
0x5fd90000 - 0x5fdb9000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\emsermi.dll
0x5fd50000 - 0x5fd8f000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\uuimi.dll
0x5fd10000 - 0x5fd46000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\filterconfig1.dll
0x5efa0000 - 0x5f844000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\swmi.dll
0x5fcc0000 - 0x5fd05000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\avmediami.dll
0x5fb80000 - 0x5fcb9000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\drawinglayermi.dll
0x5fb00000 - 0x5fb7e000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\canvastoolsmi.dll
0x705f0000 - 0x70622000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x5faa0000 - 0x5faf5000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\cppcanvasmi.dll
0x5f910000 - 0x5fa9a000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\editengmi.dll
0x5ebc0000 - 0x5ee52000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\svxmi.dll
0x5e620000 - 0x5ebb2000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\svxcoremi.dll
0x5f8f0000 - 0x5f910000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\sysdtrans.dll
0x5f890000 - 0x5f8f0000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\xstor.dll
0x5ef50000 - 0x5ef6c000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\reflection.uno.dll
0x675c0000 - 0x675cb000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\javaloader.uno.dll
0x67160000 - 0x6716a000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\jvmaccess3MSC.dll
0x5ef30000 - 0x5ef4b000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin\javavm.uno.dll
0x5f880000 - 0x5f88b000     C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\program\wininetbe1.uno.dll
0x77600000 - 0x7771a000     C:\Windows\system32\wininet.dll
0x76420000 - 0x76423000     C:\Windows\system32\Normaliz.dll
0x75bc0000 - 0x75d76000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=othman-PC:49896 abort -Dorg.openoffice.native= -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xdebug" "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=othman-PC:49896"
PATH=C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 3.4\URE\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
USERNAME=othman
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel

-------  S Y S T E M  -------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 2059928k(765200k free), swap 4119856k(2602988k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.1-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_26-b03), built on May  4 2011 00:50:59 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Thu Aug 04 16:35:56 2011
elapsed time: 7 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was having a finally block in which I was forcing a system exit. When I commented out this line everything worked OK. It seems that exiting in this code portion causes my whole OOo addon to crash.

```
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) //NOPMD
    {
        ExceptionUtils.printRootCauseStackTrace(t);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        System.out.println("Done.");
        // log.info ("Exit {}", rc);
        //I commented line below and this resolved the issue!
        // System.exit(rc);
    }
```

Comment: I thought it will be something like this, but none `System.exit()` wasn't in posted code.. Anyway, good job!

Comment: @othman i get the same error message when i press key in a text box. so should i write the follwing catch statement in my keypress event. And ExceptionUtils class doesnot exist in my ecplise. plz help me pn this

Comment: no you don't have to catch Exception. maybe you should post your code so the guys can help figure out the source for your error. the cause for such errors are sometimes mysterious

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug inside JVM native dll code. I found some help on Oracle Java homepage, you can try it, check [Error: Exception_Access_Violation](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml).

Comment: i think the issue is that when i close the SWT window , all openoffice process crashes for some reason. the whole openoffice app is terminated if i click the close button of swt window-i'm not sure what could this be?

Comment: Then i have no idea, sorry.. It may have something to do with the dynamic loading..