# Required help with the Eclipse Exception

Tags: java, exception, eclipse-rcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fatal error running SWT app from Openoffice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945615/fatal-error-running-swt-app-from-openoffice)

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7569bac9, pid=1300, tid=4856
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [USER32.dll+0xbac9]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\magnus\Desktop\eclipse-helios\hs_err_pid1300.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

i get this error message. Actually i am using nepali unicode. And all keys are properly supported expected when i press `SHIFT + 1` which is nepali one and in this case the error is shown. why actually this problem happen and any solution for this please inform me.

# C:\Users\magnus\Desktop\eclipse-helios\hs_err_pid1300.log In this file i get a long message giving all the information of thread,process.

```
Current thread (0x01a69800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4856, stack(0x00230000,0x00280000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xfffff002
```

Comment: do hs_err_pid1300.log have any extra info?

Comment: no it doesnot show any extra info......the above are the total exception generated

Comment: @j-16 sDiz Actually in the log file it is given a long information about thread, process, and VM agrgument,enviromental variable and others

Comment: this error could be thrown for many reasons. for example this was my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945615/fatal-error-running-swt-app-from-openoffice